# Errors caught show up in console

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, graphql, apollo, feathersjs

My project has 2 tests:

```
"Foods can be fetched when authenticated"

"can not be fetched when not authenticated"
```

The problem lies in the second test. It expects an error which is intercepted by a try / catch statemet. Therefore I don't expect the Error thrown in the console, yet it does.

The same problem applies using promises directly.

I have been digging in the source code of both Graphql and Feathers to solve this myself without success.

I have created a minimum reproducable code: https://github.com/jarnojellesma/feathers-graphql-test-error

```
it ('can not be fetched when not authenticated', async () => {
  const api = apolloClient();

  try {
    const res = await api.query({ query });
  } catch (e) {
    return expect(e.graphQLErrors[0].message).to.equal('No auth token');
  }

  fail('foods can be fetched when not authenticated');
});
```

**Console output**

```
Test
info: after: users - Method: create
info: after: users - Method: find
info: after: authentication - Method: create
info: after: foods - Method: remove
    foods
info: after: foods - Method: create
info: after: foods - Method: create
info: after: foods - Method: create
info: after: users - Method: get
info: after: users - Method: get
info: after: foods - Method: find
      ✓ can be fetched when authenticated (81ms)
info: error: foods - Method: find: No auth token
error:  NotAuthenticated: No auth token
    at NotAuthenticated (/home/$USER/Desktop/examples/node_modules/feathers-errors/lib/index.js:100:17)
    at /home/$USER/Desktop/examples/node_modules/feathers-authentication/lib/hooks/authenticate.js:102:31
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
NotAuthenticated: No auth token
    at NotAuthenticated (/home/$USER/Desktop/examples/node_modules/feathers-errors/lib/index.js:100:17)
    at /home/$USER/Desktop/examples/node_modules/feathers-authentication/lib/hooks/authenticate.js:102:31
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
      ✓ can not be fetched when not authenticated

  'foods' service
    ✓ registered the service


  3 passing (1s)
```

Comment: You (or someone else) had already asked the same thing here: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/713